# Python continue on gaierror using the requests library

Tags: python, error-handling, python-requests, try-catch

I'm using the requests library for python and I would like the code to continue whenever this `('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))` error occurs. For some reason my try catch is being ignored and the error causes the application to exit anyway.

My code:

```
try:
   self.doSomething();
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
   self.logger.error("A connection error occured.");
   self.logger.error(str(e) + "\n");
except Exception as e:
   self.logger.error("An error occured.");
   self.logger.error(str(e) + "\n");
```

Comment: If you just call doSomething without the try/except, what is the traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error is a [socket.gaierror](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socket.html), which is a subclass of [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#OSError) which is a subclass of [Exception](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), then the `except Exception` clause should be executed.

Try/except is a powerful tool in Python, however, if not used carefully, it can easily hide errors. Sometimes the best approach is to remove the try/except and read the full traceback. Another approach that works pretty well is to log the full traceback, unfortunately for the Python newcomer, there are ubiquitous examples of this done wrong. To get the full traceback, you need to either remove the try/except, or use

```
import traceback

try:
    risky_call()
except Exception:
    print(traceback.print_exc())
```

Or, if you have a logger configured

```
import logging

try:
    risky_call()
except Exception:
    logging.exception('')
```

Comment: I edited the code, when the gaierror is encoutered the "A connection error occured." is shown, so it must be the requests.exceptions.ConnectionError. Either way, the error should be caught and the application shouldn't exit right?

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing the full traceback - remove the try/except and update the post with the traceback. Printing string (e) is insufficient.

Comment: Removing the try/except fixed my problem, I was being stupid, there was actually some faulty code in the except block. Thanks